# Wordpress subdirectory not working on nginx server

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

I have a wordpress multi site installed on vankool.com/vietnamese but it doesn't works properly. The wp-admin shows an error too. I think it's because I am running nginx server. I have tried but .htaccess file doesn't works in this case (and read that it wont).
I also tried wordpress nginx configuration but that didn't work either for me.

I am new to nginx server. Can you help me setup nginx for wordpress multsite.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the Nginx config, but check your `try_files` directive.

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```